# Having trouble to load my java-script files after I implement "Content-Security-Policy" header

Tags: c#, asp.net, header, content-security-policy

I am implementing **Content-Security-Policy** header in my ASP.NET MVC project and my JS scripts doesn't work.

I added this tag

```html
<add name="Content-Security-Policy" value="default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' https://code.jquery.com" />
```

and as you can see I added the source of my CDN for my script file.

If I add `unsafe-inline` at the end it works but I believe that's not the point.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: "*If I add `'unsafe-inline'` at the end it works but I believe that's not the point.*" Have a look into browser console and ensure that that's is the point. You have inline scripts at the page.

Answer (score 1):

> If I add unsafe-inline at the end it works but I believe that's not the point.

As you can see you have some kinds of inline scripts on the page. Main question is - is it:

1. blocks of `<script>...</script>`
2. or inline event handlers (eg `<tag onload='...'`)
3. or javascript:-navigation (eg `<a href='void(0)'`).

Because (2) and (3) requires mandatory `'unsafe-inline'` (or code refactoring).
The first one can be allowed through `'hash-value'` or `'nonce-value'`.

Google Chrome browser in the console error messages differs all these 3 types of inline script:

1. `Refused to execute inline script ...`
2. `Refused to execute inline event handler ...`
3. `Refused to run the JavaScript URL ...`

In case of (2) you have to replace by [some way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44928377/use-addeventlistener-to-replace-each-onclick) all `<tag onclick='...'>` with `addEventListener()`.

In case of (3) you have to replace `<a href='void(0)'>` with `<a href='#'>` or any other way remove javascript navitagtion from tags.

In case of (1) you have opts:

- to add `'sha256-...'` from the violation message in the Chrome console into `script-src` directive (if there is not a lot of those).
- to use `'nonce-value'`. Easiest way is to [configure CSP](https://docs.nwebsec.com/en/4.1/nwebsec/Configuration.html) using [NWebsec](https://docs.nwebsec.com/en/latest/).
  Websec package includes `HtmlHelpers` to add script and style 'nonces'.

An example for in ASP 4:

```
@using NWebsec.Mvc.HttpHeaders.Csp
<script @Html.CspScriptNonce()>var inline = 5;</script>
```

An example for ASP Core:

```
<script nws-csp-add-nonce="true">var inline = 5;</script>
```

Alternatively you can [override `HtmlTextWriter` method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62722871/customize-web-form-script-generation/62802596#62802596) to add nonces into script/style tags.

Since you do not provide any specific info regarding you case, it can be a lot of "If-Then-Else". Anyway so wide open question can not be exactly answered.